# node.js fs remove some text

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

> /* 购买成功 */
>   "TXT_IAP_SUCCESS"                       = "Purchase Successful";
>   / * 购买失败 */
>   "TXT_IAP_FAIL"                          = "Purchase Failed";
>   / * 回复购买记录 */
>   "TXT_RESTORE_PURCHASE"                  = "Restore Purchases";
>   / * 你已重新获得你已购买的东西。 */
>   "TXT_PURCHASE_RESTORED"                 = "You've restored your purchases.";

I am using the `fs` to edit the text file. I want to remove between `/*` and `*/` text. But I don't know how to do. Thanks

Comment: Do you wanna to delete the whole comment line? or just delete words between comment mark and keep comment mark? BTW, it would be a better question if you could paste some of your code snippet.

Comment: I want to delete whole the command line

Comment: Please be more clear. What does your app do? Why do you want to remove the comments? What do you intend to do with the text left behind? Is this a command to read a file and write a file? Can another language be used instead? (e.g. UNIX bash, grep, sed, ...?)

Answer (score 1):

You could remove these commented lines use regex expression, please try following code snippet. The key point is regex **/*.**/**, it matches all commented parts.

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('./test.js', 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;

  var newValue = data.replace(/\/\*.*\*\//gim, '');

  fs.writeFile('./test.js', newValue, 'utf-8', function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('filelistAsync complete');
  });
});
```

Hope this would be helpful.

Comment: Inside your `replace()`, what is `m` for? Please?!

Comment: **m** multi line.